# Array with hashes - How to round(2) the values

Tags: ruby

I have been trying for ages. I am trying to round an array with hashes.

```
[
  {
    :email => "user_01@yorlook.com",
    :amount => 129.22500000000002
  },
  {
    :email => "user_02@yorlook.com",
    :amount => 112.67500000000001
  }
]
```

I need a method to make it look like this:

```
[
  {
    :email => "user_01@yorlook.com",
    :amount => 129.23
  },
  {
    :email => "user_02@yorlook.com",
    :amount => 112.68
  }
]
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: As a rule of thumb: don't use floats for money.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `arr` always contains `Hash` with key `amount` which is a `Float` (as in example).

```
arr.each { |hash|
 hash[:amount] = hash[:amount].round(2)
}
#=> [{:email=>"user_01@yorlook.com", :amount=>129.23}, {:email=>"user_02@yorlook.com", :amount=>112.68}]
```

Comment: You don't need `map`, just `arr.each { |h| h[:amount] = h[:amount].round(2) }`